# Need a method to pass client IP through my Apache httpd proxy for Tomcat getRemoteAddr()

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, proxy

My web service is configured with Apache httpd as a proxy to tomcat7. In my webapp I need to collect the  IP address of the client. header.getRemoteAddr(). The current configuration is only receiving the IP address of the httpd proxy (127.0.0.1). Is there a way to enable httpd to pass through the IP address of the client so that getRemoteAddr() or some other method will return it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think I found a potential solution so I am trying it out [here](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html)

Comment: The resolution was to continue to use getRemoteAddr(), but turn on a Valve in Server.xml for className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve". Once this valve is open the IP addresses will flow in through the proxy.